# Did Rene Descartes send or receive any letters (regarding mathematics) on 18.v.1638 (May 18, 1638)?

Tags: mathematics, mathematics-social-history

I dreamed about the date **18.v.1638** (May 18, 1638) last night.

As I currently do research on odd perfect numbers, and because Rene Descartes lived during the years 1596 to 1650, and as I am not a math historian, I would like to ask the experts here:

> Did Rene Descartes send or receive any letters (regarding mathematics) on 18.v.1638 (May 18, 1638)?

I tried searching via Google, using the keywords **Descartes** and **18.v.1638**, but there are too many search results (with none of them promising).  I did skim through a few of them, but did not find any *letters on mathematics sent to or received by Descartes on May 18, 1638*.

Comment: [Electronic Enlightenment](http://www.e-enlightenment.com/browse/letters/decade/1630/6) has a catalog of Descartes's letters. There are twenty from 1638, but none from May 18. However, there is one with uncertain April/May dating, and some dates were revised by editors after the discovery of his correspondence with Huygens senior, see [EMLO](http://emlo-portal.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/collections/?catalogue=rene-descartes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On checking the [Early Modern Texts for Descartes' correspondences](https://www.earlymoderntexts.com/authors/descartes), I did not find any correspondence of Descartes dated precisely to 18.v.1638. However, Descartes sent a letter to Reneri which has been dated to April or May, 1638. Because of this ambiguous dating, it seems like we don't have the knowledge that if there was a correspondence precisely on 18.v.1638.